# WordPress get template associated with category

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom template and associated it with my categories. [image]

Now what I am trying to do is check which template is associated with a specific category.

```
function custom_category_template( $template ) {

$categories = get_the_category();
$category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;

foreach ($categories[0] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
    echo $value;
    echo "</br>";
}

if ( in_category( 245 ) && !is_archive() ) {

 // the idea is to get rid of the hard coded id in the if condition above and check if a particular template is associated with the category then do the below thing


    $new_template = locate_template( array( 'custom.php' ) );
    if ( '' != $new_template ) {
        return $new_template;
    }
}

return $template;
}
```

Is there any way to do get the template name or id or something that is attached to a particular category.

I did found this one https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_template but it doesn't help me. I am on a post and I want to retrieve the current posts category's template.

Comment: Have you used ACF for template assignment to the category?

Comment: I am using Custom Category Template for template assignment.

Comment: I have category ID, from there I want to check which template is associated with the category.